# Deleting and creating the Domain Group "Everyone" in Sharepoint 2013 using Powershell CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, active-directory, csom, domain

With Powershell CSOM and SharePoint 2013, I am trying to reset the permission to the domain group "`Everyone`", with the name "`c:0(.s|true`". Therefore I want to delete and recreate it, so that all the permissions "`Everyone`" has gotten over time have been reset.

What is the correct Powershell CSOM code for executing these actions?

I also want to do the same for the group "`Everyone except external users`", but I suspect it's the same procedure as to the question above.

EDIT: I'm also satisfied with a way to iterate through the permissions and removing them one by one. What is the Powershell CSOM command for removing a groups permission to a list?

EDIT2: I'll supply the code that I've currently built the last hour. I'm getting an error in the line:

```
$list.RoleAssignments.Remove($group,$roleAssignment)
```

Error:
`An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: The collection has no
t been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been execu
ted. It may need to be explicitly requested.`

Code:

```
$permissions = $Context.Web.RoleDefinitions
$Context.Load($permissions)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

$lists = $Context.Web.Lists
$Context.Load($lists)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

$group = $Context.Site.RootWeb.EnsureUser("c:o(.s|true")
$Context.Load($group)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

foreach ($list in $lists)
{
    $list.BreakRoleInheritance($false, $true)
    foreach ($permission in $permissions){
         $roleAssignment = $null
         $roleAssignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($Context)
         $roleAssignment.Add($permission)
         $list.RoleAssignments.Remove($group,$roleAssignment)
         $Context.ExecuteQuery()
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can recreate this group.  You can go through and remove all role assignments that it has.

Comment: I am satisfied with going through and removing all role assignments, but do you know how i do that? Can't seem to be able to find the "remove specific roleassignment from list" yet.

Comment: I don't have much time to write up an answer, but the answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/eeed7fba-b6e9-4a54-8eba-0d1e449f8f6c/client-object-model-to-check-the-user-role-assignment-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious#6cfdb29b-9d8e-4f4f-aef2-667339938dc8) should get you started.  You can either use [this](http://goo.gl/52jIR6) link to convert the CSOM into PowerShell, or use [this](http://goo.gl/vPb5pW) link to execute C# code from PowerShell (probably the simpler method).

Comment: Just saw your edit.  What is $group? Is it loaded?

Comment: Yes. My code is all messy because of the ongoing edits, so I though I'd just say it was correctly initialized.
$group = $Context.Site.RootWeb.EnsureUser("c:o(.s|true")

Comment: Fixed the code. Should be more visible now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to start with in C#:

```
$lists = $ctx.Web.Lists
$ctx.Load($Lists)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($list in $lists) {    
    $ras = $list.RoleAssignments
    $ctx.Load($ras)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    foreach($ra in $ras) {        
        $ctx.Load($ra)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        if ($ra.PrincipalId -eq $everoneUserId) {
            $ra.DeleteObject();
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

That should do the job.  It's been awhile since I've used PowerShell, so there might be some issues.

Comment: I tried converting to Powershell CSOM, but even though I have some experience in that field, I can't seem to accomplish the feat. Do you have any advice regarding the matter?

Comment: @Coder1234 See update

Comment: Thanks! I had to tweek the code since it does not accept deleting "$ra" while iterating "$ra in $ras". I inserted a "break" after "ctx.ExecuteQuery". 
Therefore it does not delete ALL permissions, but in my case, each group only have one permissionlevel for each list, so this is more than sufficient.
Thanks again.